# HTML form mail to suppress notification

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I am using HTML tag form action='mailto..... so that email can be sent from client email software.

Problem is the notification confirmation dialog box,

How can this warning notification be suppressed ??

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can use anchor tag to suppress the confirmation dialog

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">click to send</a>
```

Comment: No. This poses another problem. It does opens a new email where the send button need to be pressed for sending the email. If that send can be pressed through some script would also serve as solution.

Comment: I don't think that send can be triggered by any scripting as we'll not be aware which would be the default mail composer at the client end.